# Validate Email,Phone and PAN number in single Input field in angular 7 form control

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-forms, form-control

so i want to create one input field which will tell the which type it is like mobile or email or PAN no.,so how can we do this in formcontrol

i tried using regex pattern but its not working

```
<form [formGroup]="validates_input">
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter Email/ PAN / PAN">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
<button>Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write your own validator. Using a combination of two different regexp values.

Simple expample for email

```
([a-z0-9\-\_\.]+\@[\w\d\-\_]+\.[\w]+)
```

Simple number regexp

```
([\d]+)
```

In your component file add this validator function

```
// the validator
export function checkFilterInputValidator(nameRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control:AbstractControl): {[key:string]: any} | null => {
    // if input field is empty return as valid else test
    const ret = (control.value !== '') ? nameRe.test(control.value) : true;
    return !ret ? {'invalidNumber': {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
}
```

In your component add to your control

```
inputControl = new FormControl("", 
                               [Validators.required,
                               checkFilterInputValidator(/([a-z0-9\-\_\.]+\@[\w\d\-\_]+\.[\w]+)|([\d]+)/ig)]);
```

And in your template, you have to add a field for showing an error or create a error dependent css class, i.e. a red frame of the input box to show there is an error.

```html
<form [formGroup]="validates_input">
<mat-form-field>
<div *ngIf="inputControl .errors && inputControl .errors.invalidNumber">Invalid input</div>
    <input matInput placeholder="Enter Email/ PAN / PAN">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
<button>Submit</button
```

Take a look at the documentation: [Custom validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators)